# PUT request and Header token

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, http-headers, put

I'm writing some with server API. I'm using RestKit but this question I wrote without. I don't understand why console request is working and my is not. Please help me with this.

```
-(void)uploadFile {

    NSString *URLPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.interlabs.pro/v1/texts/23041/content"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLPath]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

    [request addValue:    @"Bearer ewogICAgInR5cCI6ICJKV1QiLAogICAgImFsZyI6ICJIUzI1NiIKfQ.ewogICAgImlzcyI6ICJhcGkuaW50ZXJsYWJzLnBybyIsCiAgICAiaWF0IjogMTQ2MzY3ODg2NCwKICAgICJleHAiOiAxNDYzNjgyNDY0LAogICAgInN1YiI6IDgzCn0.SuvGXfsDDzpA5-qJtRUZi7uw98IqA8_axfTGcMVjZdw" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"];


    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];



    NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(resSrt);
}
```

And it's still doesn't not work, but console work perfectly

But [enter link description here](https://apigee.com/console/others?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.interlabs.pro%2Fv1%2Ftexts%2F23041%2Fcontent%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22headers_name_0%22%3A%22Authorization%22%2C%22headers_value_0%22%3A%22Bearer%20ewogICAgInR5cCI6ICJKV1QiLAogICAgImFsZyI6ICJIUzI1NiIKfQ.ewogICAgImlzcyI6ICJhcGkuaW50ZXJsYWJzLnBybyIsCiAgICAiaWF0IjogMTQ2MzY3ODg2NCwKICAgICJleHAiOiAxNDYzNjgyNDY0LAogICAgInN1YiI6IDgzCn0.SuvGXfsDDzpA5-qJtRUZi7uw98IqA8_axfTGcMVjZdw%22%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22put%22%7D)

[update token link](https://apigee.com/console/others?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.interlabs.pro%2Fauth%2Ftoken%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22headers_name_0%22%3A%22Authorization%22%2C%22headers_value_0%22%3A%22Bearer%20ewogICAgInR5cCI6ICJKV1QiLAogICAgImFsZyI6ICJIUzI1NiIKfQ.ewogICAgImlzcyI6ICJhcGkuaW50ZXJsYWJzLnBybyIsCiAgICAiaWF0IjogMTQ2MzY3ODg2NCwKICAgICJleHAiOiAxNDYzNjgyNDY0LAogICAgInN1YiI6IDgzCn0.SuvGXfsDDzpA5-qJtRUZi7uw98IqA8_axfTGcMVjZdw%22%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22body_parameters_name_0%22%3A%22login%22%2C%22body_parameters_value_0%22%3A%22alfaspa%22%2C%22body_parameters_name_1%22%3A%22password%22%2C%22body_parameters_value_1%22%3A%22fgj342rd%22%2C%22undefined%22%3A%22%5Cu0001%5Cu0001%22%2C%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22post%22%7D)

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: `message": "expired token"` seems clear enough...

Comment: @Marc token have an expire time. @Teja I have `missing authentication token`. U can use `update token link`  and try this out

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine and result is that token is expired.
But you should not use deprecated methods like "NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest", then you should check error, when handling results from internet it is utf8 most of the time and not ascii. Then when logging strings use NSLog(@"%@", theString) to avoid problems if the content of theString contains formating specifiers.

Comment: I have this log with normal token ‘{  "error": {  "id": "38fa281a-a954-434e-b15e-a7f251601e98",  "code": 403,  "message": "missing authentication token"  } }' and I used NSURLSession and had same result.‘ if u use new token from second link u will have another result

Comment: Both tokens give me "message": "expired token".
Edit: Make sure that data comes not from lokal or remote cache!

Comment: @ MacGritsch , if you go with second link and copy new token, and put it in a first link header, You will get `HTTP/1.1 302 Found`. But if you put new token in the code you will get ` "code": 403, "message": "missing authentication token"`

Comment: please post here the links ans tokens to use because on the site that you linked, the urls are broken (url-encoded twice or whatever).

Comment: `ewogICAgInR5cCI6ICJKV1QiLAogICAgImFsZyI6ICJIUzI1NiIKfQ.ewogICAgImlzcyI6ICJhcGkuaW50ZXJsYWJzLnBybyIsCiAgICAiaWF0IjogMTQ2MzcyMzMzNSwKICAgICJleHAiOiAxNDYzNzI2OTM1LAogICAgInN1YiI6IDgzCn0.Hl0S3gs9cSmxkOjV5OUGY7r2lmmL-b0SvqEjiPX0P7Y` You can use only one link in one time, @ MacGritsch

Comment: with the headeder value above: `"message": "bad token"`

Comment: I`m sorry here is a good one ewogICAgInR5cCI6ICJKV1QiLAogICAgImFsZyI6ICJIUzI1NiIKfQ.ewogICAgImlzcyI6ICJhcGkuaW50ZXJsYWJzLnBybyIsCiAgICAiaWF0IjogMTQ2MzczMDE4MCwKICAgICJleHAiOiAxNDYzNzMzNzgwLAogICAgInN1YiI6IDgzCn0.kmBwmQtUChOCuePh_IKJVslFx050UBVKvxT_tdTelJI